# Add a google map route to calendar (S7 Edge)

Tags: calendar, google-maps, google-calendar

In iOS you can add a google map route to your calendar app, but in android (Galaxy S7 Edge) you can't. EVEN to google calendar! Why is it? Am I missing something? Why does iOS have better integration of GOOGLE maps than android?

Comment: [calendar to map possible with a different app](https://support.google.com/maps/forum/AAAAQuUrST8UHwIOpp-Nac?hl=en). Map to calendar not possible. Why ? Google knows best

Comment: @beeshyams fair enough, I just wanna make sure I'm not missing something.